# Display first post of a term in taxonomy template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have my template `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` (here, 'catmaison').

In this taxonomy, I have 3 terms ('au-fil-du-temps', 'elaboration-distillation', 'plantes-epices').

Each terms of this taxonomy are displayed in my main menu.

I would like to display the first post of each term when i click in the menu.

Example : 
When I click on 'Au Fil Du Temps' in the menu, i would like to display the first post.

You can see my current code bellow :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- CONTENT PAGE -->
<section class="sous-pages ptb-60" id="product-page" style="background: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>'); height: 700px;">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>taxonomy catmaison</h1>

        <div class="row">

            <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type'             => 'maison',
                'posts_per_page'        => 1,
                'orderby'               => 'ASC',
                'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'catmaison',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'au-fil-du-temps',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'catmaison',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'elaboration-distillation',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'catmaison',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => 'plantes-epices',
                    ),
                ),
            );

            // Custom query.
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Check that we have query results.
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            // Start looping over the query results.
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();

            ?>                

                <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
                <div class="col-xl-4 offset-xl-6 product-type-2">
                    <h1>single produit</h1>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="intro-texte pb-20"><?php the_field('page_introduction'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_field('project_description'); ?></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="float-left"><?php previous_post_link('%link','<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/img/general/arrow_left_shadow.png" />'); ?></div>
                    <div class="float-right"><?php next_post_link('%link','<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/img/general/arrow_right_shadow.png" />'); ?></div>
                </div>
                <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->

            <?php

            } // End while 
            } // End if

            else { echo '<p>Aucune actualité trouvée</p>'; } ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 

        </div><!-- End Row -->

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Comment: Try repacing `tax_query` with this:
`'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'catmaison',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => get_queried_object()->slug,
                    ),`
in code

Comment: **Corrected:** Try replacing `tax_query` with this: `'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'catmaison', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => get_queried_object()->slug, )),` in your code

Comment: @QaisarFeroz There are not visible modifications .. But it says that your code do the same things that my previous code i think

Comment: Although not tested,  my code should restrict the output to display one post from  the clicked term. While your  code in question gets one post from all three term irrespective of currently clicked (queried) term.